# add (how long ago) time to detailTextLabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uilabel, nsdate

I have a table view and at cell for row at index path i have

```
cell.textLabel.text = username;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = // here i would like to display time
```

in the detailtextLabel i would like to display the time: 5 mins ago so it shows how long ago the message came.

How would it be possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do it yourself you can use this great library : https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit

Look for TTTTimeIntervalFormatter.

```
NSDate *aDate = ... ;
TTTTimeIntervalFormatter *timeIntervalFormatter = [[TTTTimeIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [aDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Comment: In NSDate *adate should I put NSDate alloc init

Comment: Depends what you want to display. If you want to display when something was created, you would put there the creation date of the something.

Comment: So NSDate alloc initwithtimeinterval:1 or ?

Comment: Or if I'm getting the data from parse.com would I pass in the retrieved message

Answer (score 0):

The server or the backend must be sending you a timestamp. Mostly it's a Unix timestamp.

You can create an NSDate object from it and then convert it into a user friendly format and show as an NSString.

Would look something like

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimeStamp];
NSDate *dateFromatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *formatString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = formatString;
```

Comment: I'm using parse.com. I am new to iOS could you please show me how

Comment: i get a few errors on the first line it says unixTimeStamp undeclared identifier. second line says NSDateFormatted can not be passed to NSDate. third line says NSDate does not declare setDateFormatt. i declared 2 properties `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;`
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;`

Comment: @smithyy For that you should post another question. Also, you probably need to read up on parse as well.